# C#: Error de sintaxis: falta el operando después del operando

Tags: c#

Utilizo la siguiente función para filtrar el listado de un datagridview

```
private void SetFilterDataGrid( ) {
  bindSource.Filter = "Fecha BETWEEN " + datepckFechaInicial.Value.ToString( ) + " AND " + datepckFechaFinal.Value.ToString( );
}
```

No entiendo el error, he utilizado el filtro en una consulta y funciona

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El error es porque las fechas deben ir entre comillas, ya sean dobles o simples. 
Pon comillas simples para encerrar las fechas en tu consulta:

```
private void SetFilterDataGrid( ) {
  bindSource.Filter = "Fecha BETWEEN '" + datepckFechaInicial.Value.ToString( ) + "' AND '" + datepckFechaFinal.Value.ToString( ) + "'";
}
```

De esta manera las fechas quedan entre comillas, ya que la comparación de las fechas se da como cadena.

Comment: Hola Walter, gracias por responder. Cuando el error es tipografico, lo que se debe hacer es comentar como hiciste, y en vez de responder, pulsar en reportar/votar cierre para que se cierre como No reproducible > fallo tipografico. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b lo tendré presente. Saludos

Comment: Y de esta manera no puedo utilizar el operador BETWEEN.

Comment: Por cierto el error permanece si en lugar de BETWEEN utilizo <= AND >=

Comment: Se puede utilizar sustituyendo BETWEEN por >= AND <=